# while using whatsapp with twilio, can I still use Facebook Whatsapp api directly?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

facebook recently allow everyone to send marketing messages, and create marketing templates.

but when try to create whatsapp template in Twilio dashboard there is no such option as marketing message(just transaction)
I wonder if its ok for me to create templates directly through Facebook or it will mess thing up and I must use Twilio directly?

there is more missing options like attaching media or header to template

**twilio dashboard (no marketing category):**
[image]

**facebook dashboard:**
[image]

tldr: is it ok to use Facebook api directly when using Twilio to register my Whatsapp number?

Comment: also looks like variable in buttons url are not supported in twilio, so I cant have a template with dynamic url like if I was using facebook api directly

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, so I am checking internally at Twilio. Hopefully will have an answer for you soon.

Comment: thanks meanwhile I got accepted into the Content API beta, and even there no Marketing templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked on this question with Twilio product support and the answer was:

> I don't believe this would be possible, as the number and configuration would be tied directly to Twilio. You could certainly try, but this is not something we can offer guidance on or provide support for if you proceed.

I don't have my own WhatsApp number to try with, so I can't verify or test whether you can use the Facebook APIs directly either.

If you are in the Content API beta and you are finding that it still doesn't provide you the features you need, then I recommend raising that with the beta team, who will work to bring it to the API.

Comment: Thanks for the replay really appreciate it, do you know if twilio allow me to keep my number but use the whatsapp cloud api directly?(without using the twilio api for whatsapp obviously)

Comment: I don't honestly know. I did just see [this person on Reddit's experience and what they did](https://www.reddit.com/r/twilio/comments/va6bis/twilio_whatsapp_api_implamantion_is_too_limited/). Maybe that helps?